How to decompose the conditional posterior prob?
I am learning bayesian inference now. A problem I encountered a lot of time is, when I need to calculate or simplify the posterior prob., I don't know how should I begin, according to what I have.
For example, suppose $$ y\mid\mu, \sigma^2 \sim N(\mu_j, \sigma^2)$$
and $$ \mu_j \sim N(\theta, \tau^2) $$
where $y_i\mid\mu_j,\sigma^2 $ are iid, $\mu_j\mid\theta, \tau^2$ are iid.
How to decompose $p(\mu_j \mid \sigma^2, \tau^2, \theta,y)$ and $p(\theta \mid \sigma^2, \tau^2, \mu,y)$?
i.e., $p(\mu_j \mid \sigma^2, \tau^2, \theta,y) \propto ?$
If you want to use other example to explain the general way to decompose the posterior dist, that will also help a lot!

To consider a distribution on $\theta$ requires a prior on $\theta$ and $\mu$ is single, therefore cannot be written as iid.

Where you say "$y_i$ are iid", I take it you mean $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ are iid, i.e. there are multiple random variables $y_i,$ not just one. And I would assume you meant conditionally i.i.d. given $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ (I would have said that). But where you say "$\mu\mid \theta, \tau^2$" are i.i.d.", what does that mean? More than one $\mu\text{?}$ If so, does the distribution of $y_i$ depend on $\mu_i$ and not on $\mu_j$ for $j\ne i\text{?}$ How are we to understand this?

@MichaelHardy Hi I modify the question, you are right there are couple groups of y, so does mu

@Xi'an Sorry I don't understand what you say. I modify the question to make it clear, could you please take a look?

It appears that you are taking $\sigma^2, \tau^2,$ and $\theta$ to be known.
You have $y\mid \mu \sim \operatorname N(\mu, \sigma^2).$
So you have a likelihood function
\begin{align}
L_{\mu\,\mid\,y}(m) = {} & \text{constant} \times e^{-(y-m)^2/(2\sigma^2)} \\[6pt]
\propto {} & e^{-(y-m)^2/(2\sigma^2)}
\end{align}
where $\text{“}{\propto}\text{”}$ means proportional as a function of $m,$ not as a function of $y$ or of anything else. Things not depending on  $m$ are considered "constant" in this context.
If you have multiple observations $y_i$ that are conditionally independent given $\mu,$ then you multiply the likelihood functions
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n e^{-(y_i-m)^2/(2\sigma^2)} = e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-m)^2/(2\sigma^2)}. \tag 1
$$
Algebra tells us that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-m)^2 = n(\overline y - m)^2 + n\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\overline y)^2
$$
where $\overline y= (y_1+\cdots+y_n)/n.$ Thus line $(1)$ above becomes
$$
e^{-( n(\overline y-m)^2 )/(2\sigma^2)} \cdot e^{-(\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \overline y)/(2\sigma^2)}.
$$
The second factor does not depend on $m,$ so this is proportional as a function of $m$ to the following:
$$
e^{-( n(\overline y-m)^2 )/(2\sigma^2)}
$$
This is the same as:
$$
e^{-( (\overline y-m)^2 )/(2(\sigma^2/n))}.
$$
So it is just as if, instead of observing $y_1,\ldots, y_n \mid \mu \sim\text{i.i.d.} \operatorname N(\mu,\sigma^2),$ we had observed only $\overline y\mid \mu \sim \operatorname N(\mu,\, \sigma^2/n),$ i.e. just one observation rathern than $n$ observations, but with a smaller variance. Thus our likelihood function is
$$
L_{\mu\,\mid\, y_1,\ldots,y_n}(m) \propto e^{-( (\overline y-m)^2 )/(2(\sigma^2/n))}.
$$
The prior distribution of $\mu$ is
$$
f_\mu(m)\, dm \propto e^{-(m-\theta)^2/(2\tau^2)} \, dm.
$$
Here I include $\text{“}dm\text{”},$ whereas with the likelihood function that would be grossly wrong. That is because this is a probability distribution – a measure on the line $(-\infty,+\infty)$ – whereas the likelihood function is not.
The posterior distribution is proportional to the product of the prior and the likelihood:
$$
L_{\mu\,\mid\, y_1,\ldots,y_n}(m) \cdot f_\mu(m)\, dm \quad \propto \quad e^{-( (\overline y-m)^2 )/(2(\sigma^2/n))} \cdot e^{-(m-\theta)^2/(2\tau^2)} \, dm.
$$
Thus we must find a sum:
$$
\frac{ (\overline y-m)^2 }{2\sigma^2/n} + \frac{(m-\theta)^2}{2\tau^2}.
$$
The common denominator is $2\sigma^2\tau^2/n,$ and the numerator of the resulting fraction is:
$$
\tau^2(\overline y - m)^2 + \frac{\sigma^2} n(m-\theta)^2.
$$
Now write this as a quadratic polynomial in $m$:
\begin{align}
& \left( \tau^2 + \frac{\sigma^2} n \right) m^2 - 2\left(\tau^2\overline y + \frac{\sigma^2} n \theta \right) m + \text{(terms not depending on $m$)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \left( \tau^2 + \frac{\sigma^2} n \right) \left(m^2 - 2\left( \frac{\tau^2 \overline y + \frac{\sigma^2} n \theta }{\tau^2 + \frac{\sigma^2} n} \right) m + \text{(terms not depending on $m$)} \right). 
\end{align}
Now complete the square:
$$
\left( \tau^2 + \frac{\sigma^2} n \right) \left(m - \left( \frac{\tau^2 \overline y + \frac{\sigma^2} n \theta }{\tau^2 + \frac{\sigma^2} n} \right) \right)^2  + \text{(terms not depending on $m$)}.
$$
This is the numerator of the aforementioned fraction, whose denominator we said is $2\sigma^2\tau^2/n.$
So the power to which $e$ will be raised is $(-1)$ times the following:
\begin{align}
& \frac{\left( \tau^2 + \frac{\sigma^2} n \right) \left(m - \left( \frac{\tau^2 \overline y + \frac{\sigma^2} n \theta }{\tau^2 + \frac{\sigma^2} n} \right) \right)^2}{2(\sigma^2/n)\tau^2} \\[8pt] = {} & \frac{ \left(m - \left( \frac{\tau^2 \overline y + \frac{\sigma^2} n \theta }{\tau^2 + \frac{\sigma^2} n} \right) \right)^2}{2\cdot\frac{2\sigma^2\tau^2}{\sigma^2 + n\tau^2}} = \frac{(m-\text{something})^2}{2\cdot\text{something}}.
\end{align}
So the two "somethings" are the posterior expected value and the posterior variance:
\begin{align}
\operatorname E(\mu\mid y_1,\ldots, y_n) & = \frac{\tau^2 \overline y + \frac{\sigma^2} n \theta }{\tau^2 + \frac{\sigma^2} n} = \left( \frac{\frac1{\sigma^2/n}}{\frac1{\sigma^2/n} + \frac1{\tau^2}} \right) \cdot \overline y + \left( \frac{\frac1{\tau^2}}{\frac1{\sigma^2/n} + \frac1{\tau^2}} \right) \cdot \theta, \\[8pt]
\operatorname{var}(\mu\mid y_1,\ldots, y_n) & = \frac{\sigma^2\tau^2}{\sigma^2 + n\tau^2}.
\end{align}
Observe that the posterior mean is a weighted average of the prior mean $\theta$ and the sample mean $\overline y,$ with weights proportional to the reciprocals of their variances $\sigma^2/n$ and $\tau^2.$ The bigger the variance, the less information; the bigger the reciprocal of the variance, the more information, so the reciprocals of the variances give you the weights.
Observe that in the expression for the variance, when $n=0$ then the variance becomes $\tau^2,$ the prior variance. And as $n\to\infty,$ the variance approaches $0,$ i.e. as the sample grows, you become very sure of the value of $\mu.$

I think a clumsy trivial mistake in algebra may have messed up the variance. I'll be back$,\ldots\qquad$

$\qquad \uparrow\qquad$ok, I've fixed that. $\qquad$
